# What qualifications/criteria do you need to meet to teach at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I'm curious to how good, perhaps wealth of knowledge is a better term, Hogwarts teachers were in their respective fields?

As there doesn't seem to be a University level of education in the Hogwarts world (from what I gather it seems to be "on the job" training after NEWTs).

Would the Hogwarts teachers be closer to University level Professors in the real world who, in theory, are world experts in their discipline or are they just closer to school teachers with Dumbledore being a unique exception?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm not talking about teaching ability but rather knowledge/authority in the subject matter.

Comment: I think that this question is too broad as it stands. Evaluating the strengths and qualities of each individual teacher (or even just giving an overview) would require an excessively long answer. Answers would also be pretty subjective  (who's to say what counts as "good"?). You should find a way to narrow the focus of your question, perhaps to one attribute which you're particularly interested in.

Comment: Also, the short answer is that you have to be an expert in your field to teach at Hogwarts. Unless you're the DADA teacher, in which case they'll take any mug who comes in off the streets.

Comment: My question was more focused towards what requirements you need to meet to be a teacher at Hogwarts. For example, to be a University Professor you would need a Ph.D., multiple publications in high quality journals, supervised successful Ph.D. students etc.

Now while I'm not looking for such a specific list for a Hogwarts teacher, is there any sort of board measure they use to determine who is "worthy" or qualifies as having the ability in their subject to be a teacher at Hogwarts?

Comment: Maybe consider changing the title to 'What qualifications do you need to teach at Hogwarts?', or something similar. I'm pretty sure there's no specified criteria, though. Dumbledore just appoints who he wants.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - or the ministry (in the case of Umbridge). It does seem to be the most promising wizards from Hogwarts though, Voldemort was expected to become a teacher *straight after leaving*.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - There seems to be some sort of age requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the requirements to teach at Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60890/what-are-the-requirements-to-teach-at-hogwarts)